# How to use jubula's OS execute externalcommand on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, jubula

I'm working with **jubula** on ubuntu and I have some issue running the **os_execute_externalcommand** function.

Directory : /home/ramzi/desktop/test

Executable: jtest.jar

arguments : java -jar jtest.jar

argument_seplit : #

ps: -the jtest.jar file is working  from terminal and it's executable from its directory.
    -the function works fine on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command's parameters like this:

```
Executable: java
Arguments : -jar jtest.jar
```

This should work if 'java' was added to the `PATH` of the OS.

I believe the command works for you on Windows because you associated the '.jar' file extension to be opened by an installed JVM (you've made them De-facto executables)

Comment: that did not work on Ubuntu is there an other solution